# Breakout collision using 2D Rectangles?

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, collision-resolution

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace BreakOut
{
    class Field
    {
        public static Field generateField()
        {

            List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();
            for (int j = 0; j < BlockType.BLOCK_TYPES.Length; j++)
                for (int i = 0; i < (Game1.WIDTH / Block.WIDTH); i++)
                {
                    Block b = new Block(BlockType.BLOCK_TYPES[j], new Vector2(i * Block.WIDTH, (Block.HEIGHT + 2) * j + 5));
                    blocks.Add(b);
                }

            return new Field(blocks);
        }

        List<Block> blocks;
        public Field(List<Block> blocks)
        {
            this.blocks = blocks;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Ball b)
        {
            List<Block> removals = new List<Block>();     
            foreach (Block o in blocks)
            {
                if (o.BoundingBox.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)b.pos.X, (int)b.pos.Y, Ball.WIDTH, Ball.HEIGHT)))   //collision with blocks
                {
                    removals.Add(o);
                }
            }

            foreach(Block o in removals)
                blocks.Remove(o);           //removes the blocks, but i need help hitting one at a time
        }

        public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            foreach (Block b in blocks)
                b.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add collision so that when the ball hits against a block, then one of the blocks disappears.

The problem I'm having is: When the ball hits the block, it removes them all in one instance.

Comment: You can read this tutorial on AppHub : http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_rectangle

Comment: may be this [2D Polygon Collision Detection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/2D-Polygon-Collision-Detection) can help you.

Comment: There is a faily good explanation of creating the game pong which I used to understand 2D collision detection using XNA. It starts from scrath and builds to a full working game (I like those versus the theoretical how-to's); [XNA - 2D Bounding Box Collision Detection Demonstrated with the game Pong ][1] [1]:http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180069-xna-2d-bounding-box-collision-detection/

Comment: As far as I can tell, the collision code in `Update` looks correct.  Maybe the issue is somewhere else?  Have you tried debugging this line-by-line to see where the problem is?

Comment: Well there is [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com).  But we prefer you ask questions here, so students in similar situations can find this thread and learn from it in the future *(inactive chat rooms are deleted)*

Comment: "...it removes it all in one instance" what does that mean? The ball doesn't bounce back?

Comment: i could show you via teamviewer or skype or something! i really need help on this please help me.

Comment: The way I handle collision in this situation is to give your ball a collision radius (float) and check to see if it intersects the bounds of the block's rectangle. Get the center of your ball and then set your collision radius from there. If I have more time a bit later I'll type out some code for you. Good luck!

Comment: Edit your post with some screen shots or try to describe it. I'm at work and it's best to document these things in the questions anyway (more helpful to future visitors).

Comment: You can create a SO chat room and I can join it to answer additional questions about this topic.

Comment: byte, when you get out of work can you help me ?

Comment: Can you post your Ball class?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8947/whats-a-good-way-to-do-collision-with-2d-rectangles-can-someone-give-me-a-tip

Comment: Indeed, the Ball class is where your issue is going to be.

Comment: Hmm.. if you change your for each loop to a for loop you can directly remove the block object that was hit. I'm not a 100% sure, but if I were to guess your problem is that blocks.Remove(o) is removing all instances of type Block. That, or your collision detection is detecting each block as a hit and putting it into removals. I suggest putting a breakpoint at the beginning of your Update function and start stepping through it

Comment: So is this homework Javier?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727220 - did you try running a debugger like I suggested?

Answer (score 5):

### What you probably want

At the moment, your code only removes any `Block`s (they may be one or more) that the `Ball` collides with. You want the Ball to bounce off of the Blocks in addition to removing them. What you have is called *collision detection* (reporting when a collision has happened). What you'd like to have is called *collision response* (doing sensible things once a collision is detected).

You probably want the ball to bounce as if it had hit a wall.

### Collision response

[image: side bounce]

The ball has hit the top, bottom or one of the sides. In this case, the ball should reverse its horizontal direction if it has hit a block to its left or right, or reverse its vertical direction if it has hit a block from the top or bottom.

At the moment, your collision detection only detects whether the ball is touching a block. For getting it to bounce realistically in the way described, you must also know which direction it should bounce in. You need more information: Which direction was the block in?

One way of finding out is to examine the intersection of the bounding boxes:

[image: bounding box intersection]

The coordinates of the corners of the block and of the ball can easily be used to calculate the intersection between the block and the ball. It is quite intuitive that if the ball collides with the top or bottom of the block, this intersection's **width** will be greater than its **height**. Conversely, if the ball collides with the left or right side of the block, this intersection will have a greater **height** than **width**. There are various other methods of detecting the same thing, but this one is fast.

With this information, you can make the ball bounce in the correct direction.

### Multi-block collisions

You may find that sometimes the ball intersects with multiple blocks at the same time, in which case the bounce may have to be in another direction which I haven't covered yet! You can for all cases draw similar diagrams for these cases and examine how you could go about telling them apart.

Comment: can you help me with my code?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to do more than doodle and type things. :) Try it and come back with the results! It's faster for people to help if you have a partly finished solution.

Comment: What program are you using for your doodles Aku? Using a tablet too? They are well done!

Comment: lol ^ and byte can you help me once your out of work? :( i been working on this for so long and can't get it to work properly

Comment: Not to be rude @Javier but you are getting help. If you can't apply the help or at least tell everyone where the help is failing then you're not going to get much further. (Unless someone is kind enough to take time out of their day to go one-on-one which is asking a lot)

Comment: ^^ mike can you go one-on-one with me? :D

Comment: I think you missed the point there. If I could, I would but I'm at work and will be for most of the night.

Comment: how about tomorrow mike? i have to finish this by monday, im like 95% done with this game , i just need this collision working then im done

Comment: @Javier - If the 5% of your game left to do is collision, then you are definitely not 95% done.

Comment: i just made that percentage up, but i am really close to finishing this game, better @DMan?

Comment: @Javier It really doesn't seem like you're interested in trying to solve your own problem so no, I'm afraid I won't be helping you. StackExchange is for QA i.e. you ask a well-thought out question and others answer to the best of their ability. If you're just going to keep asking people to do your work for you then go somewhere else.

Comment: @Byte I realise only now that I never replied to you! D: I use [MyPaint](http://mypaint.intilinux.com/) with a tablet. I use [this script](http://sirupsen.com/a-simple-imgur-bash-screenshot-utility/) to quickly take a screenshot and upload it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the basic problem here is to get the ball to bounce off a block. It looks like the block is disappearing fine.

The first step is to figure out when the ball touches a block. You have done that.

The second step is to figure out which side of the block it hit, so you know which way to bounce it. In practice, it is easier, since you only need to know whether the ball hit a horizontal or a vertical side. It is also much simpler with square blocks than with rectangular blocks.

The third step is to reflect the ball's motion in the appropriate direction

Here is some pseudocode for the second and third steps:

```
int x = (blockRect.X + (blockRect.Width / 2)) - (ballRect.X + (ballRect.Width / 2));
int y = (blockRect.Y + (blockRect.Height / 2)) - (ballRect.Y + (ballRect.Height / 2));
if (Abs(x) > Abs(y))
{
    // reflect horizontally
    ballSpeedVector.X = -ballSpeedVector.X;
}
else
{
    // reflect vertically
    ballSpeedVector.Y = -ballSpeedVector.Y;
}
```